# How to create a ns3 scenario from teh external python file?

Tags: python, ns-3

I have a python file that creates a reinfrocement learing scenario .Now I need to call the ns3 module in this file to create corresponding scenario in ns3 .How do I import the ns module in my file and pass relevant parameters to the ns3 mjodule?

I have tried to import the specific path of ns3 module in my file ,but it still reminded me that "No module named ns".How can I solve this problem?